# Android RelativeLayout placing elements whith styles

Tags: android, styles, android-relativelayout

I want to place two elements in line, one to the right and one to the left. I want to do this from the code... and use styles.

First I tried it with static layout.xml: This works good:

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

then I created styles,

```
   <style name="t1" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentLeft">true</item>
</style>

<style name="t2" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentRight">true</item>
</style>
```

and tried:

```
RelativeLayout rel = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    rel.setLayoutParams(params);

    TextView t1 = new TextView(this);   
    t1.setText("balbla_1");
    t1.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.t1);


    TextView t2 = new TextView(this);
    t2.setText("balbla_2");
    t2.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.t2);


    rel.addView(t1);
    rel.addView(t2);

    setContentView(rel);
```

But I see elements overlapping, as the style for align was not accepted... is it possible to use styles for such procedures?

Comment: i don't remember if there is a view.setstyle method. if it exists, you can try it. i post this answer with my phone.

Comment: no.,. no setStyle.. but this setTextAppearance accept the style.. for example I see that size of the text has changed.. but Align option was not accepted

Comment: it seems you must pass style in the view constructor. so you can use new textview(context,null, style)

Comment: no, that do not have any effect. setTextAppearance was better in case it has taken some of style parameters. by setting a style in a new textview it has no effect at all....

Answer (score 1):

As specified in javadoc, setTextAppearence works only for some attributes:

```
/**
 * Sets the text color, size, style, hint color, and highlight color
 * from the specified TextAppearance resource.
 */
```

But you can do something like this

```
    TextView t1 = new TextView(this);
    t1.setText("balbla_1");
    t1.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.t1);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams t1_params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    t1_params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);


    TextView t2 = new TextView(this);
    t2.setText("balbla_2");
    t2.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.t2);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams t2_params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    t2_params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);


    rel.addView(t1, t1_params);
    rel.addView(t2, t2_params);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  "setTextAppearance() only works for some attributes" - very important. And of course, like SO MANY OTHER THINGS in Android, totally annoying. Put another way, any "layout_x" parameters stored in a style will be completely ignored when calling setTextAppearance. So, sometimes styles work as expected, sometimes they don't. How to find out? Scour documentation. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Linear Layout ? like;

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/o1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/o2" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: but what should that bring.. I want to get same result as I did in layout.xml but programaticaly.